# Decoding styles in C#

Tags: c#, decoding

By using the following code, I managed to decode a given hexadecimal string. In C#, using its library functions, I could decode a hexadecimal value in to ASCII, Unicode, Big-endian Unicode, UTF8, UTF7, UTF32. Can you please tell me how can I convert a hexadecimal string in to other decoding styles such as ROT13, UTF16, western European, HFS Plus, etc..

```
{
    string hexString = "68656c6c6f2c206d79206e616d6520697320796f752e";
    byte[] dBytes = StringToByteArray(hexString);

    //To get ASCII value of the hex string.
    string ASCIIresult = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dBytes);
    MessageBox.Show(ASCIIresult, "Showing value in ASCII");

    //To get the Unicode value of the hex string
    string Unicoderesult = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(dBytes);
    MessageBox.Show(Unicoderesult, "Showing value in Unicode");
}

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
    int NumberChars = hex.Length / 2;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars];
    using (var sr = new StringReader(hex))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i++)
            bytes[i] =
                Convert.ToByte(new string(new char[2] { (char)sr.Read(), (char)sr.Read() }), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your answers, they were very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [GetEncoding()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding.aspx)

```
 string utf16string = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-16").GetString(dBytes);
 MessageBox.Show(utf16string , "Showing value in UTF-16");
```

Check out possible [Code Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) Decoding Styles.

And use this fragment to convert string to byte[]

```
    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hexstring)
    {
        var bytes= new byte[hexstring.Length / 2];
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < hexstring.Length; i += 2, j++)
                bytes[j] = Convert.ToByte(hexstring.Substring(i, 2), 0x10);
        return bytes;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get other Encoding objects by the method [Encoding.GetEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c.aspx), which accepts codepage or encoding name. e.g.

```
//To get the UTF16 value of the hex string
string UTF16Result = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-16").GetString(dBytes);
MessageBox.Show(UTF16Result , "Showing value in UTF16");
```